# TIME in mysql minus 1 hour

Tags: php, mysql

i am selecting the time from a DATETIME field in mysql as a valid RFC2822 dateformat.
But i want mysql to select the date but directly subtract 1 hour of the time.

This is my script now:

```
    $sql_select_bezig = "SELECT 
                            DATE_FORMAT(verzonden_op,'%a, %d %b %Y %T') AS rfc_date,
                            message_id
                                    FROM
                                        email_tracking
                                    WHERE 
                                        DATE(verzonden_op) > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)";
```

Now it is only selecting the date and displays it like Sun, 14 Sep 2014 20:13:33 +0100.
That's ok, but how do i subtract 1 hour?

Comment: Use `verzonden_op - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`, see [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 0):

Select DATE_FORMAT(Date_SUB(date, 2, HOURS)...) AS ...  from ...

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL statement, we can substitute an expression for a column name.

Anywhere column name **`verzonden_op`** appears in your statement, you can replace that with the expression that VMai suggested...

```
verzonden_op - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```